# Should I build a different model for each subset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, categorical-data

I have a dataset which has categorical variable *class* I am trying to solve a *regression* problem

I am not understanding whether I should build a model on entire dataset and consider variable *class* as one of the input variable or for each class should I build a different model altogether.

What are *general* rules which can help me deciding between two approaches.

This is a sample of how my data looks like

```
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
|   Class    | X1 | X2  |     Speed       |
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
| Class1     | 12 | 123 |              10 |
| Class2     | 14 | 120 |              32 |
| Class3     | 15 |  34 |              12 |
|   .        |  . |   . |               . |
|   .        |  . |   . |               . |
|   .        |    |     |                 |
|  Class 300 | 23 |  13 |              45 |
+------------+----+-----+-----------------+
```

`Class` is the input categorical variable and I have around 300 classes. The output variable is `Speed`. I am trying to predict the speed with variables `Class`, `X1`, `X2`.

Should I build a model for each `Class` separately. So when I know input type is `Class1` I will select model built for `Class1`. When input type is `Class2` I will use model built for `Class2` and so on. Also the values in `Class` variable can repeat meaning `Class1` can come 4 times, `Class2` can come 8 times etc

Other way I was thinking is to include `Class` itself as a variable and just build one model.

I don't know which would be the *correct* way for it

Comment: 1) pls edit your post for consistency - you mention both "around 10 classes" and "around 300 classes" 2) there is not a "correct" way to do it; although the first approach would naturally be to built a single model with `class` as an input variable, you should definitely experiment with the other approach, too, if you feel so 3) the question is arguably off-topic here, as it is not about *programming* but about modeling methodology, for which the appropriate sites are [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @desertnaut Edited. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

There is no generally accepted *correct* way. Most people will tell you to try both methods and use the one that works the best with your data. A couple things to note, though:

- Does each class have enough data points to build an accurate model? If not, combining all the classes (or some that are similar) might be the better approach.
- If you do need to combine classes, you might need to normalize your data if any of the other parameters are not on a similar scale. (See [Feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) for reference.)

It's hard to say more without knowing the nature of your data.

Comment: I know its really difficult but just wanted a fair baseline of what people do. A general overview is what I want. Thanks though